# Access to asp:Tablerow style from codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have an asp table on page with some rows. There is a button inside one of row cells. Then I clicked on the button the row is hide. I use function for that:

```
function AttachmentRemove(clickedButton)
    {
        try {
            var clickedRow = clickedButton.parentNode.parentNode;            
            clickedRow.disabled = true;
            clickedRow.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            clickedRow.style.display = 'none';
            v
        }
        catch (err) {            
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

Then I clicked a different button that send page on the server and I try to get the rows of table and read its properties. But Visible property is true for all rows.
Why?
How can I send Hidden/Visible row property to server?

Answer (score 0):

To access Tablerow or any element in code behind, you need to add attribute **runat="sever"**. Then the element will be accessible by id.

```
<asp:Table ID="MyTable" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="MyRow1">
        <asp:TableCell>Some value<asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```